# In-line R expression returns incorrect value

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

If the R code in Rmd file reuses the same variable name, the inline r expressions seem to return the last value of this variable regardless of the location of the inline expression. Is there away to avoid this behavior except for making sure the same variable name is not reused in different parts of the document?

The reproducible example

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---


```{r}
df <- cars
nrow(df)
```

The dataset has `r nrow(df)` rows.


```{r}
df <- iris
nrow(df)
```

The dataset has `r nrow(df)` rows.
````

This produces the following output

[image]

I am using:
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

rmarkdown_1.4
knitr_1.15.1

Comment: For me it works as expected in both R Notebook and R Markdown on Win 7, R 3.3.2, rmarkdown 1.3, knitr 1.15.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your header, you are "previewing" your file, which does not actually run your code from scratch. You have to knit it to HTML to have it run so that your in-line code is correct.

**Problem Header**

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---
```

**Solution Header**

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: 
    html_document: default
    html_notebook: default
---
```

**Other Notes**

The previous solution has two problems. First, from the RMarkdown documentation, "Inline expressions do not take knitr options" (see end of http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html)

Second, the previous answer's YAML is not formatted properly forcing RStudio to actually knit the file. The proper formatting would generate the same problem you are having

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: 
    html_notebook: default
---
```

Comment: This indeed solves the problem!!!! And now I also understand why. I am wondering though whether it is a bug in implementation of R notebook, since the "problem header" is the default header that RStudio defines in the template that is generated when I open a new R notebook. (File -> New File -> RNotebook).

Comment: Right. And running Ctrl+Shift+K does not actually knit the document, it previews it. However, if you change the option which says "Preview Notebook" to "Knit to HTML", then it changes the header and does what you want it to do. And then Ctrl+Shift+K will work (if you use keyboard shortcuts)

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that if I knit HTML as you proposed, the output does not have those nice features as the R notebook output such as an interactive way to hide or show code in the HTML. So even though it is a solution the original problem, it is may not be a perfect one. Any idea how to enable the same HTML features, such as hiding code and still have correct inline expressions?

Comment: Just add html_document: folding: show to the top of your file. See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, we can specify `cache = TRUE`

````
---
title: "R Notebook"

output: 
html_notebook: default


---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
```


```{r}
df <- cars
nrow(df)
```
````

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. Still getting the same 150 rows in both cases... What am I missing?

Comment: @Sasha I am using Rstudio version 1.0.136.  Not sure if it is due to version difference

Comment: @Sasha Just checked without using the cache=TRUE in my version.  It is working fine.  So, probably, it is a version difference

Comment: I am using the same version. Here is my sessionInfo.R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.15.1

Comment: @Sasha Here is the packages based on sessionInfo `[1] rmarkdown_1.4        knitr_1.15.1         RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0 RevoUtils_10.0.2     RevoMods_10.0.0     
 [6] MicrosoftML_1.0.0    mrsdeploy_1.0        RevoScaleR_9.0.1     lattice_0.20-34      rpart_4.1-10`

Comment: my knitr and rmarkdown versions are the same as yours. I am lost here...

Comment: @Sasha I downloaded the preview version only a few days back

Comment: This works as expected for me on ubuntu, Rv3.3.3,  rmarkdown v1.3

Comment: @user20650  I used R 3.3.2 and on windows 10

Comment: Perhaps you want to use an RMarkdown document instead of an R Notebook.

Comment: Alternatively, I suggest you use a different variable name for the two chuncks and re-execute them.